# can you create indexes on embedded objects in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Coming from a mongodb background, I'd like to set up a document with an embedded collection.

For instance if I have a profile object

Profile

- name : string
- followers : [
  name: string
  ]

such that it has an embedded collection of followers.

Is there a way that I can create an index on Profile so that I can query for all profiles where Profile.Followers includes myUsername?

In short I can query for profiles I'm following from a dynamoDB table?

In mongo I can easily do this by setting up an index on Profile.followers and doing an $in query.  Is there something similar for dynamodb?

This documentation suggests there is nothing like an in clause

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently DynamoDB does not support indices for non scalar types (i.e. Set, List, or Map data types - see here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html). If you have a separate users table, you can keep track of all profiles you are following in a Set/List attribute.

Comment: so if I wanted to do a query for all profiles I'm following plus my profile - is there a way to do that in one query (like a sql join) or would I have to make two seperate queries and combine them client side?  i.e. profiles where name == "me" and profiles where name in ['friend1', 'friend2'].  Is there something like an $in clause in dynamodb queries?  I couldn't find any in the docs.

Comment: You would need to make two separate queries and combine them on the client side. You are essentially storing the profile "foreign key" in the "following" Set/List attribute of the users table - to retrieve all the corresponding profiles, you can use GetItem requests to the profiles table using each profile key.